# Terminal Commands Difference between Ubuntu and Manjaro

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, command, archlinux, manjaro

I just finished downloading Manjaro. My experience with Linux thus far has mainly been with Ubuntu (also a little bit with Kali(basically the same terminal)).

Anyways, my question is what are the main differences between the terminal commands in each kernel.

For example:
Ubuntu = aptitude
Manjaro = pacman

I know Manjaro is based on Arch Linux but are the command line commands basically the same? There is so much documentation on Arch that I would be able to find anything I need if I looked for it in Arch Docs/link/searches/articles/etc rather then Manjaro Docs/links/searches/articles/etc.

Side question:
Are there any KEY differences that a newcomer to Manjaro should know?

Comment: I'm ready to review my answer cause I don't really understand "Are there any KEY differences that a newcomer to Manjaro should know?"

Answer (score 4):

> I know Manjaro is based on Arch Linux but are the command line commands basically the same?

To quote the [Manjaro team](https://manjaro.github.io/Note-About-Manjaro/):

> - Manjaro is developed independently from Arch, and by a completely different team.
> - Manjaro is designed to be accessible to newcomers, while Arch is aimed at experienced users.
> - Manjaro draws software from its own independent repositories. These repositories also contain software packages not provided by Arch.
> - Manjaro provides its own distribution-specific tools such as the Manjaro Hardware Detection (MHWD) utility, and the Manjaro Settings Manager (MSM).
> - Manjaro has numerous subtle differences in how it works when compared to Arch.

So, explained by the Manjaro Team, Manjaro has several differences with Arch. However, the command line commands **are basically the same**.

---

> There is so much documentation on Arch that I would be able to find anything I need if I looked for it in Arch Docs/link/searches/articles/etc rather then Manjaro Docs/links/searches/articles/etc.

**Be awake**, before searching in [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org), search in the [Manjaro Wiki](https://wiki.manjaro.org) because there are some cases that are Manjaro specific.

---

> My question is what are the main differences between the terminal commands in each kernel?

The main differences are **the packages manager** and the **location of certain files** in the root directory. But if you never touched Ubuntu "core" files, you probably don't have to know this second part ;).

To give you a basic example **here's a little comparison table** for each package manager.

```
.---------------------------------.------------------------.------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.
|                                 |          Arch          |                                                            Ubuntu                                                            |
:---------------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------:
| Package Manager                 | Pacman                 | Apt-Get                                                                                                                      |
:---------------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------:
| Command to Refresh and Upgrade  | pacman -Syu            | apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade                                                                                       |
:---------------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------:
| Command to install wget         | pacman -S wget         | apt-get install wget                                                                                                         |
:---------------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------:
| Command to install sublime-text | pacaur -S sublime-text | sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3 && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer |
'---------------------------------'------------------------'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
```

You can find a full list comparing the different package manager in [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Rosetta) and [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Upgrading_packages) for more information about [Pacman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman)

Pacaur is an [AUR helper](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helpers). In other words, it helps you install packages from the [AUR](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository) (Arch User Repository) where there is over 38,200 users-submitted packages.